# Reference needed: Homology of the blow-up

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Given an algebraic variety $X$ over the complex numbers.
Let $V$ be a subvariety of $X$ and $\pi_V \colon X' \rightarrow X$
be the blow-up of $X$ at $V$.
It is posible in general to compute the singular
homology groups of $X'$ in terms of the singular homology
of $X$ and $V$?

I know that for cohomology groups there are results
in EGA.5 and EGA.7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you put any restrictions on $V$?

Comment: Any reference will serve. If it is generally, better.